# File Upload Making as Public - Image is not Showing in HTML img tag

Tags: lightning-web-components, force.com-sites, fileupload, public

I am Uploading the Image from LWC page by using `lightning-file-upload` and Making the Image as Public accessible as Below

```java
ContentVersion cv = [select id from contentversion where contentdocumentid =:documentId];
ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
cd.Name = 'Test';
cd.ContentVersionId = cv.id;
cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser= true;
cd.PreferencesLinkLatestVersion=true;
cd.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit=false;
cd.PreferencesPasswordRequired=false;
cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload= true;
insert cd;
```

```java
SELECT DistributionPublicUrl FROM ContentDistribution WHERE ContentDocumentId
```

**Sample URL:**
https://psas--sandboxone.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/6w0000008jRU/a/6w000000Gn7s/Lic0.Hgi5VwyYli3xJcMMjJs6mauT7fSWxUCTROTjyc

If I use the above URL in HTML `img` tag, Image is not showing, Can anyone Please help me solve this issue

```html
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                       <img style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;border:none;max-width:100%;outline:none;width: 250px;vertical-align: bottom;"
                                           width="32"
                                           src="https://psas--sandboxone.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/6w0000008jRU/a/6w000000Gn7s/Lic0.Hgi5VwyYli3xJcMMjJs6mauT7fSWxUCTROTjyc"> 
                                       
                                   </div>
```

Comment: That URL is likely for the page that will load the image not the image itself. The image url in you case is https://psas--sandboxone--c.documentforce.com/sfc/dist/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_Jpg&versionId=0686w000000IfWZ&operationContext=DELIVERY&contentId=05T6w000001nCAU&page=0&d=/a/6w000000Gn7s/Lic0.Hgi5VwyYli3xJcMMjJs6mauT7fSWxUCTROTjyc&oid=00D6w0000008jRU&dpt=null&viewId=

Comment: @manjit5190 how you frame this URL.

Comment: Can you Please help me to Understand on this?

Comment: I am not really sure how can we generate that. I'll wait for someone who has worked on it to provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `DistributionPublicUrl` Use `ContentDownloadUrl`

`SELECT ContentDownloadUrl FROM ContentDistribution WHERE ContentDocumentId`

You must get the `ContentDownloadURL` in the Image Source of the Site that you want to use.